# Jenkins Git Tag/Push Error

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like clarification on:

- how jenkins master nodes and worker nodes communicate with git
- how both nodes use credentials and ssh plugins to authenticate with git
- when to use Credentials plugin vs SSHAgent plugin

Right now, I believe that the Master Node stores all credentials and then passes these credentials to the worker agents. This makes me believe that only one node - the master node - should have ssh keys for git.

Thus far this seems to be true because, when a build is trigged on master, the worker node is able to run git clone and git init even though no ssh keys are configured on worker agent.

```
Started by user deploy-user
Replayed #23
18:01:03 Connecting to https://api.github.com using deploy-user/****** (username-with-password)
Obtained Jenkinsfile from a12ea59545db96fc8681dbdd5d44923108c01b40
[Pipeline] node
Running on nodejs in /home/server/jenkins/workspace/K-Front_feature-jenkinsfile-KHCSHNIRHLZUOTSCIQPWI7
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
Cloning repository https://github.com/WaterBottleInce/Frontend.git
> git init /home/server/jenkins/workspace/K-Front_feature-jenkinsfile-KHCSHNIRHLZUOTSCIQPWI7 # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/WaterBottleInce/Frontend.git
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials username-with-password
> git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/WaterBottleInce/Frontend.git +refs/heads/feature-jenkinsfile:refs/remotes/origin/feature-jenkinsfile
> git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/WaterBottleInce/Frontend.git # timeout=10
> git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/feature-jenkinsfile:refs/remotes/origin/feature-jenkinsfile # timeout=10
> git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/WaterBottleInce/Frontend.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/WaterBottleInce/Frontend.git
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials username-with-password
> git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/WaterBottleInce/Frontend.git +refs/heads/feature-jenkinsfile:refs/remotes/origin/feature-jenkinsfile
Checking out Revision a12ea59545db96fc8681dbdd5d44923108c01b40 (feature-jenkinsfile)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f a12ea59545db96fc8681dbdd5d44923108c01b40
Commit message: "removes error in customworkspace"
> git rev-list a12ea59545db96fc8681dbdd5d44923108c01b40 # timeout=10
```

So why then does this step:

```
steps{
  sh('git remote -v')
  sh('git show-ref')
    sh('git tag -a $BRANCH_NAME.$BUILD_NUMBER -m "git sha is $GIT_COMMIT"')
    sh('git push origin HEAD:development --tags')
}
```

result in this error:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy-Staging)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[K-Front_feature-jenkinsfile-KHCSHNIRHLZUOTSCIQPWI7] Running shell script
+ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/WaterBottleInc/Reactjs-Front.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/WaterBottleInc/Reactjs.git (push)
[Pipeline] sh
[K-Front_feature-jenkinsfile-KHCSHNIRHLZUOTSCIQPWI7] Running shell script
+ git show-ref
a12ea59545db96fc8681dbdd5d44923108c01b40 refs/remotes/origin/feature-jenkinsfile
[Pipeline] sh
[K-Front_feature-jenkinsfile-KHCSHNIRHLZUOTSCIQPWI7] Running shell script
+ git tag -a feature-jenkinsfile.24 -m git sha is a12ea59545db96fc8681dbdd5d44923108c01b40
[Pipeline] sh
[K-Front_feature-jenkinsfile-KHCSHNIRHLZUOTSCIQPWI7] Running shell script
+ git push origin HEAD:development --tags
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

this line from the error print out above:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

completely throws me off because I have no idea where it is looking for a username.

Can someone please help me out?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
steps{
  sh('git remote -v')
  sh('git show-ref')
  sh('git tag -a $BRANCH_NAME.$BUILD_NUMBER -m "git sha is $GIT_COMMIT"')
  sh('git push origin HEAD:development --tags')
}
```

fails because credentials that are defined in Master Node are not automatically bound/passed into build jobs.

To bind credentials, we need the [suite of Credentials Plugins](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs). Once those are installed, then we make use of the [withCredentials() function](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/workflow-integration-credentials-binding-plugin) to pass in the credentials needed to authenticate/communicate with git.

Read this post on [jenkins-user forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/rv7SVnBHZnc) if you need more clarification